# Expresso Store: Item Title

Tags: expresso-store

I am attempting to create a repeater list for all the items in the cart, however I am having trouble generating the title and and custom fields.

```
{items}
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="product" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:350px"><p class="item-title">{title}</p><p>Size: Large</p></td>
                                <td style="width:75px"><input style="width: 40px;" type="text" name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" /></td>
                                <td style="width:260px"><p class="item-title">{price}</p></td>
                                <td style="width:260px"><p class="item-title">{item_subtotal}</p></td>
                                <td style="width:75px; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="remove_items[{key}]" value="1" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            {/exp:channel:entries}
                            {/items}
```

All the short-tags used by the store function as expected, however all the titles and custom fields will only grab the data from the newest entry and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what the issue was, seems obvious to me now. I was using an exp:channel:entries tag wrapped around the template to generate the fields for the page itself (just title in this case), this of course caused an issue because I was calling another exp:channel:entries tag inside of it.

In order to get around this I would need to place the entire {exp:store:checkout} -- all the stuff --{/exp:store:checkout} in its own embed, not just the 2nd {exp:channel:entries} tag.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to solve issues like this is to `{embed}` the script you wish to repeat.

For example:

```
{items}
    {embed="cart/_items.html"}
{/items}
```

and within your template, eg `cart/_items.html`

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <tr>
        <td style="width:350px"><p class="item-title">{title}</p><p>Size: Large</p></td>
        <td style="width:75px"><input style="width: 40px;" type="text" name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" /></td>
        <td style="width:260px"><p class="item-title">{price}</p></td>
        <td style="width:260px"><p class="item-title">{item_subtotal}</p></td>
        <td style="width:75px; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="remove_items[{key}]" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Embedding helps to eliminate issues causes when nesting loops in Expression Engine.

See [Embedding Templates within Other Templates](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html)

Comment: While that would be my usual approach in this situation Bradley, it doesn't seem to work as expected with Expresso Store. By doing to we are able to repeat the correct entries, however we lose our functional {item} and subtags that Expresso Store uses. Good advice in general for this sort of issue, but doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Ahh valid point. I didn't think of that.